Surface Integrals with Cartesian coordinates
I have the unusual situation where I require a method to compute surface integrals, but I am restricted to Cartesian coordinates. The method I am using is the following: given a 3D space with coordinates $x^i=(x,y,z)$, a 3D spatial metric $\gamma_{ij}$, and a spatial unit normal to a surface $s_i$, I define the 2D metric of the surface
$$
\sigma_{ij}=\gamma_{ij}-s_is_j
$$
I then need to pick coordinates on the surface itself, and I will call them $\theta^A$ where [$i,j\in(1,2,3)$ and $A,B\in(1,2)$]. The projection onto the surface is defined by
$$
e^i_A=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\theta^A}
$$
and I can form the 2D metric projected onto the surface
$$
\sigma_{AB}=\sigma_{ij}e^i_Ae^j_B
$$
So I can in principle pick $\theta^A=(x,y)$, and together with a surface definition $z(x,y)$ (with multiple solutions for a closed surface), I can transform the closed surface integral into an integral over a 2D region $Z$
$$
\oint f dS = \int_Z f \sqrt{\mathrm{det}(\sigma_{AB})}\, dxdy
$$
My question is the following. It seems correct to have $e^i_1=(1,0,\partial_xz)$, $e^i_2=(0,1,\partial_yz)$ (Method 1) as I described, but just based on some experiments I have done, having $e^i_1=(1,0,0)$, $e^i_2=(0,1,0)$ (Method 2) also seems to work, giving correct answers up to a consistent factor of $1/3$. For example, computing the surface area of a sphere with radius $R$ with Method 1, doing the 2D integral over the disk of radius $R$ with $z(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$, I get $4\pi R^2$ as expected, and Method 2 gets $(4/3)\pi R^2$. This seems to be consistent for other integrands other than 1, where Method 2 gives $1/3$ of the correct answer. Is there a mathematical reason for this, or is this a coincidence?
